# Can I use react-i18next trans tag inside React helmet tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-helmet

The following code

```
const x = (<Trans>Welcome</Trans>);
<helmet><title>{ `${x}` }</title></helmet>
```

does not show title = Welcome. It shows title = object,object

Hence, I wonder can I use react-i18next tag inside react-helmet tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have custom JSX tags within Helmet. It only supports all valid head tags: `title, base, meta, link, script, noscript, and style tags` and their attributes. However you can use the `t` function from i18n for translation

```
// the hook
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent () {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return <helmet><title>{t('Welcome to React')}</title></helmet>
}
```

or with HOC like

```
// the hoc
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent ({ t }) {
  return <helmet><title>{t('Welcome to React')}</title></helmet>
}

export default withTranslation()(MyComponent);
```

[Documentation of react-18n provides more details](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start)

Comment: I face this.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Please check what is the version of react- and react-dom in your app, if you have version <16.8.0 the you need to use the second approach

Comment: 2nd do work. But can I do it by not creating another javascript file?

Comment: you do not need to create another javascript file

Comment: I thought export default need to be in another javascript file. Anyway I try to put everything in 1 javascript file. This is how I did ->
 const mm = withTranslation()(MyComponent);